# NavigationView Unresponsive

Tags: android

I am creating a navigationview in android.I have added items under draweritems under menu folder.Whenever I clicked a menuitem a toast appeared before,but now it is unresponsive.Below is the code.Help me please...

draweritems.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/motel"
            android:title="Motel"
            android:icon="@drawable/motel"
            >

        </item>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/packages"
            android:title="Packages"
            android:icon="@drawable/packages">
        </item>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/ayurveda"
            android:title="Ayurveda"
            android:icon="@drawable/ayurveda">
        </item>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/marketing"
            android:title="Marketing"
            android:icon="@drawable/marketing">
        </item>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/Tours"
            android:title="ConductedTours"
            android:icon="@drawable/tours">
        </item>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/Locate"
            android:title="Locate"
            android:icon="@drawable/locate">
        </item>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/News"
            android:title="News"
            android:icon="@drawable/news">
        </item>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/Login"
            android:title="Login"
            android:icon="@drawable/login">
        </item>
    </group>

</menu>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
import android.content.Context;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
    import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        private Toolbar toolbar;
        private Context context=this;
        private NavigationView navigationView;
        private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                    Toolbar toolbar=(Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
             navigationView=(NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
            navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                    Log.i("Clicked", "Clicked motel");
                    if (menuItem.isChecked()) {
                        menuItem.setChecked(false);
                    } else menuItem.setChecked(true);

                    drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                    switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.motel:

                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Motels", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            return true;
                        case R.id.packages:
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Packages", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            return true;
                        case R.id.ayurveda:
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ayurveda", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            return true;


                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });
            drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
            ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawerLayout,toolbar,R.string.openDrawer, R.string.closeDrawer){



                @Override
                public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                    // Code here will be triggered once the drawer closes as we dont want anything to happen so we leave this blank
                    super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                }

                @Override
                public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                    // Code here will be triggered once the drawer open as we dont want anything to happen so we leave this blank

                    super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                }
            };

            //Setting the actionbarToggle to drawer layout
            drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);

            //calling sync state is necessay or else your hamburger icon wont show up
            actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();



        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if(id==R.id.ayurveda){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Clicked Ayurveda",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;
            }
            //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }


    }
```

main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
        app:menu="@menu/draweritems"
        app:theme="@style/NavigationViewStyle">

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/relative"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

styles.xml:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->

    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>

</style>
<style name="NavigationViewStyle">
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>

    <!-- menu item text size-->
    <item name="android:listPreferredItemHeightSmall">80dp</item><!-- menu item height-->
</style>
```

Comment: post navigationview xml file

Comment: Posted navigationview

Comment: you have to set selector to identify that which item selected

Answer (score 1):

This code change

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
```

The following code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener
```

I'm not sure, but I hope you make it.